# Xamarin forms - How to detect whether the device is touch device or not?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

I am developing an app using xamarin forms cross-platform PCL project. I need to know if I can detect whether the device is touch device or not? Is it possible to detect this?

Comment: refer this link https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/other_ux/gestures/detect_a_touch/

Comment: Are you planning to make a TV app ? is that why you are asking ? if so you can know that from the android project in main activity.

Comment: @BraveHeart how? do you have sample code

Comment: I have sent you the sample , does that answer you question ?

Comment: yes it helped. thank you @BraveHeart

Comment: then maybe you can mark it as an answer so it would help others :)

Answer (score 2):

XF does not know if the device is touch or not, but you can detect the kind of device you're running on using `Device.Idiom`. If you get `TargetIdiom.Desktop` you know that, in addition of a possible touch screen, the user probably also has a keyboard and a mouse.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are asking this to make a TV app . 
Well unfortunatly at this moment Xamarin.Forms cannot find that, however you can do this in the main Activity like follows

```
 var uiModeManager = (UiModeManager) GetSystemService(UiModeService);
if (uiModeManager.CurrentModeType == UiMode.TypeTelevision)
{
     _isTv = true;

}
else
{
_isTv = false;

}
```